# Are read-only of global variables and writing to private class members "false sharing" in openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

I am writing a program where a bunch of different classes, all stored in a vector, do parallel operations on private members using public data structures.  I'd like to parallelize it for multiple processors using OpenMP, but I have two questions about two of the operations in the code, both of which are indicated in comments in the example below that shows a reduced form of the program's logic.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <vector>

class A {
  private :
    long _i;
  public :
    void add_i(long &i) { _i += i; }
    long get_i() const { return _i; }
};

int main()
{
  timeb then;
  ftime(&then);
  unsigned int BIG = 1000000;
  int N = 4;
  std::vector<long> foo(BIG, 1);
  std::vector<A *> bar;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    bar.push_back(new A());
  }
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
  {
    for(long i = 0; i < BIG; i++)
    {
      int thread_n = omp_get_thread_num();
      // read a global variable
      long *to_add = &foo[i];
      // write to a private variable
      bar[thread_n]->add_i(*to_add);
    }
  }
  timeb now;
  ftime(&now);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    std::cout << bar[i]->get_i() << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << now.millitm - then.millitm << std::endl;
}
```

The first comment addresses the read from the global foo.  Is this "false sharing" (or data sloshing)? Most of the resources I read talk about false sharing in terms of write operations, but I don't know if the same applies to read operations.

The second comment addresses writing operations to classes in bar. Same question: is this false sharing?  They are writing to elements in the same global data structure (which is, from what I've read, sloshing), but only ever acting on private data within the elements.

When I replace the OpenMP macro with a for loop, the program is faster by about 25%, so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: Your example is strange.  You said a bunch of different classes but I think you mean a bunch of different objects of the same class?  And by bunch you mean four.  That's not very many.  But it's also set to the number of threads which seems arbitrary.  Why don't you show us your non-parallelized code and then we can show you how to parallelize it best.

Answer (score 1):

Modern memory allocators are thread-aware. To prevent false sharing when it comes to modifying each instance of `class A` pointed to by the elements of `bar`, you should move the memory allocation inside the parallel region, e.g.:

```
const int N = 4;
std::vector<long> foo(BIG, 1);
std::vector<A *> bar(N);
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(N)
{
  int thread_n = omp_get_thread_num();
  bar[thread_n] = new A();
  for(long i = 0; i < BIG; i++)
  {
    // read a global variable
    long *to_add = &foo[i];
    // write to a private variable
    bar[thread_n]->add_i(*to_add);
  }
}
```

Note also that in this case `omp_get_thread_num()` is called only once as opposed to `BIG` times as in your code. The overhead of calling a function is relatively low, but it adds up when you do that many times.

Comment: I don't think that's the case with `i`, variables declared inside the parallel region are private automatically.

Comment: Fixed. I kind of missed the fact that `i` is declared in the loop construct.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest sharing problem is the `bar[thread_n]`. The reading of `foo[i]` is less of an issue.

Edit: Since `bar[thread_n]` is holding pointers, and the pointee is what gets updated, there is little or no sharing. You may still benefit from loading a "lump at a time" into each CPU-core, rather than reading one or two items per CPU-core from each cache-line. So below code may still benefit. As always when it's a matter of performance, benchmark a lot (with optimisation enabled), as different systems will behave different (depending on compiler, CPU architecture, memory subsystems, etc, etc)

It would be better to "lump" a few items at a time in each thread. Something like this, perhaps:

```
const int STEP=16;

for(long i = 0; i < BIG; i+=STEP)
{
  int thread_n = omp_get_thread_num();
  int stop = std::min(BIG-i, STEP);   // Don't go over edge. 
  for(j = 0; j < stop; j++)
  {
     // read a global variable    
     long *to_add = &foo[i+j];
     // write to a private variable
     bar[thread_n*STEP + j]->add_i(*to_add);
  }
}
```

You may need to adjust "STEP" a bit to make it the right level.

Comment: his bar objects are `new` on the heap.  Who knows where they end up.  On my laptop allocation granularity is 32 bytes and cache line is 64.  possible that two objects will end up in the same cache line.

Comment: But the vector `bar` is a contiguous piece of memory.

Comment: That's the vector of pointer, `vector<A*>` rather than `vector<A>`

Comment: @Anycorn: And where are the pointers stored? In a vector, which is a contiguous piece of memory. Same (well, sort of) as if you wrote `A* bar[1000000]`.

Comment: the values of vector<A*> arent modified tho - the memory it points too does but that doesn't affect the vector<A*>

Comment: Ah, you are right. Good point. However, each processor loading it's own cache-lines of `foo` and `bar` would still have a small benefit.